# QGIS performance wtih many unique value widgets in the attributes form

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm creating a QGIS 3.8 workflow and made about 15 attributes as unique values generated from the data already in the form but now the info view and attribute table that's used to open almost instantaneously now takes ~30s or more to open and about ~15s when data is updated.

When the options are known is it better to use the Value Map option -this takes longer to setup so is not ideal? or is there some other tweek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use-case, using Value Map will be certainly faster. I tested with a large layer and Value Map was much faster than Unique Values widget. There is an easy way to set up Value Map, using the `Load Data from Layer` option which allows you to select a layer and field to setup the value map automatically. The setup using this method should be much easier than manually loading the unique values.

[image]